# includes() not returning true for substring

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm having trouble figuring out why this function isn't returning results if the keyword is a substring.

```js
const string = 'cake';
const substring = 'cak';
console.log(string.includes(substring));
// returns true
```

But when I try to do something similar here I'm not getting the result I expect.

```js
function filterByKeyword(array, keyword) {
  return array.filter((x) =>
    x.keywords
      .map(function(x) {
        return x.toLowerCase();
      })
      .includes(keyword.toLowerCase())
  );
};

const array = [{
    "id": 1014,
    "keywords": [
      "Sesame Street",
      "Cake",
      "Party",
      "Birthday"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 1015,
    "keywords": [
      "Sesame Street",
      "Party",
      "Birthday"
    ]
  }
];

console.log(filterByKeyword(array, 'cak'))
// returns []

console.log(filterByKeyword(array, 'cake'))
// returns an array with the correct object
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Array includes !== String includes `["sesame street",
     "cake",
     "party",
     "birthday"].includes("cak")`

Comment: To follow up on what @epascarello said, you need to check if *each* string `.includes()` the substring, not the *entire* array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to check if any of the strings in the array includes the keyword.

```js
function filterByKeyword(array, keyword) {
  return array.filter((x) => 
     x.keywords.some(w=>w.toLowerCase().includes(keyword.toLowerCase()))
  );
};

const array = [
{
  "id":1014,
  "keywords":[
     "Sesame Street",
     "Cake",
     "Party",
     "Birthday"
  ]
},
{
  "id":1015,
  "keywords":[
     "Sesame Street",
     "Party",
     "Birthday"
  ]
}];

console.log(filterByKeyword(array, 'cak'))
```

Answer (score 1):

String includes is not the same as Array Includes. Array includes needs a full match of the index. It is not a partial match. Couple of ways to do it. The simplest is to just make the array a string and look for a match

```js
const array = [
{
  "id":1014,
  "keywords":[
     "Sesame Street",
     "Cake",
     "Party",
     "Birthday"
  ]
},
{
  "id":1015,
  "keywords":[
     "Sesame Street",
     "Party",
     "Birthday"
  ]
}];

function find(partial) {
  return array.filter(function (obj) {
     return obj.keywords.join(",").toLowerCase().includes(partial)
  });
}

console.log(find('cak'));
```

Other option is using some()

```js
const array = [{
    "id": 1014,
    "keywords": [
      "Sesame Street",
      "Cake",
      "Party",
      "Birthday"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 1015,
    "keywords": [
      "Sesame Street",
      "Party",
      "Birthday"
    ]
  }
];

function find(partial) {
  return array.filter(function(obj) {
    return obj.keywords.some(function(txt) {
      return txt.toLowerCase().includes(partial);
    })
  });
}

console.log(find('cak'));
```

Answer (score 1):

you are actually applying `includes()` function to the array not on string that's the issue.
here I'm using reduce for this purpose.

```
function filterByKeyword(array, keyword) {
  return array.filter((x) =>
      x.keywords
          .reduce(function (result ,x) {
              return result + x.toLowerCase().includes(keyword.toLowerCase())
          }, false)
          

  );
};

const array = [{
    "id": 1014,
    "keywords": [
      "Sesame Street",
      "Cake",
      "Party",
      "Birthday"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 1015,
    "keywords": [
      "Sesame Street",
      "Party",
      "Birthday"
    ]
  }
];

console.log(filterByKeyword(array, 'cak'))
// returns [{...}]

console.log(filterByKeyword(array, 'cake'))
///return [{...}]
```